# Неправильно работает date_diff

Tags: php

Почему выводит 0 0 0, если разница 50 минут?

```
$hour1 = new DateTime('2017-11-24 22:31:29', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow'));

$hour2 = new DateTime('2017-11-24 23:21:29', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow'));

$interval = $hour1->diff($hour2);

echo $interval->format('%h %m %s');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $interval->format('%h %i %s');
                            ^----------- надо так
```

`m` - Месяцы

http://php.net/manual/ru/dateinterval.format.php